# How to build summary page containing multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have a multiple databases and tables comprised of business name, location and licensing data. I use DataTables to display the data and GeoServer / Leaflet to display maps. I'm working with over 125k businesses and about 20 different data points for each.

My challenge is is I need to create a profile page for one business, city, or zip code. The user will get to that profile page from links in my DataTables or map.  That profile page will display have counts of all similar businesses for a variety of data I can only determine through a range of queries against 1 or more tables such as:

1. all businesses of the same type in the same zip code
2. all businesses of the same type in the same census tract
3. all businesses within a 1000' radius of the business

I would provide examples but, I am unable to even test this concept because I don't know which direction to go. If you could help me understand what approach I should follow I would be grateful. I've been stuck for months (doing other things but, this has been a wall). Should I:

1. Create a rather complex view in my database that contains all the counts for each of the areas (the number of potential combinations would be immense), and then a PHP query in the actual page that essentially calls those counts? or,
2. Create a series of queries in the actual webpage?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice problem... Could you please specify some partial problems you need to solve? I see you have "multiple databases" - so do you look for a way how to query those databases at the same time? Or you already use Foreign data wrapper or Pl/Proxy extension? Or you must run queries separately on every database/ instance using some OS scripts and collect results and process them into some target database?

Comment: That's my question. What I should be looking for and trying? I have a database of all business licenses in a state, another for crime, another with census information etc. I want to create a page for a city that has subtotals and totals for business categories (from DB1), crime in that city for DB2, and population data from the census from DB3. My goal is to have one page for one city that will be dynamically updated. I don't know if that should be a query to all 3 DBs when the user clicks a link to that city profile page, or if I should have a 4th DB with all the data totals and query that.

Comment: Solution depends totally on amount of data complexity of your queries and users' demands regarding speed of report. Also how quickly data change if it OK to have for example results for yesterday or if users demand to see changing number in "real time". If yesterday's data are enough you can generate reports (numbers) over night and only show results. But if data change quickly and "real time" view is necessary then you might need to calculate some aggregations for example every 5 or 15 minutes and show results from them...

Comment: Thanks for your help JosMac. The information does update daily and users would not need any real-time accuracy. When you say to create the reports daily is that data stored in a separate table, then when the user selects criteria, ie. all donut shops in LA, within a certain census tract (all data I have for every record) I just ping that table with that query? Or, do I run the query when the user selects their criteria from a range of dropdowns or selects? (Sorry if going in circles, I'm not sure)

Comment: OK, since you have so complicated environment and it can happen some databases can be unreachable in some moments I would recommend you to create some new database especially for reporting and store all results in it. This way you will not have problems to show results (as far as your report database will run of course). If you will calculate partial results on every database and later just select them from report database and store there or you will run all queries remotely from report database depends mainly on how strongly are separate databases utilized or how reliable connections you have

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll work on that and appreciate your feedback. Now I at least have a direction to point which has been puzzling.